# simplexml warnings and errors

Tags: php, simplexml

I am having trouble with some php scripts which parse xml files.  These scripts have been running without error for months, and are all crashing all of a sudden today.  No changes were made to the code or environment.  I am relatively new to php, so any help would be appreciated.

Here's the errors I am seeing:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: c:/server/public_html/dev/temp.xml:1: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: HR line 1 and body in C:\Server\public_html\dev\index.php on line 31

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: LED).</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.32</h3></body> in C:\Server\public_html\dev\index.php on line 31

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in C:\Server\public_html\dev\index.php on line 31

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: c:/server/public_html/dev/temp.xml:1: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: HR line 1 and html in C:\Server\public_html\dev\index.php on line 31

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.32</h3></body></html> in C:\Server\public_html\dev\index.php on line 31

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in C:\Server\public_html\dev\index.php on line 31

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: c:/server/public_html/dev/temp.xml:1: parser error : Premature end of data in tag body line 1 in C:\Server\public_html\dev\index.php on line 31

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.32</h3></body></html> in C:\Server\public_html\dev\index.php on line 31

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in C:\Server\public_html\dev\index.php on line 31

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: c:/server/public_html/dev/temp.xml:1: parser error : Premature end of data in tag html line 1 in C:\Server\public_html\dev\index.php on line 31

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.32</h3></body></html> in C:\Server\public_html\dev\index.php on line 31

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in C:\Server\public_html\dev\index.php on line 31

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Server\public_html\dev\index.php on line 35
```

Comment: Can we see the XML you are trying to load? Looks like it is in fact HTML, which is not valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the "XML" you're processing is actually an error page, in HTML, returned by the server you are trying to fetch XML from.

Try opening the URL you are passing to `simplexml_load_file()` in a browser, or dumping out the result of `file_get_contents($your_url_here)` to see what the error message actually says.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your post variable syntax (e.g some apis not like html tags etc.)
It's very important to find where your fault is in. Use at least 2 debug method.

For example use below and check your sending data:

```
file_put_contents("/your folder/page.txt", $post_data);
```